# Set a global/system wide environment variable based on value of connected monitor in macOS?

Tags: macos, shell, environment-variables

I would like to have an environment variable set based on whether a particular screen is connected to a macbook. This would allow the font size in the Terminal (Kitty) to be automatically changed based on this value.

I am able to do this in my .zsh file to set a env variable:

```
if system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep -q "Studio Display"; then export DISPLAYNAME="studiodisplay"; fi
```

Which sets that variable to "studiodisplay", provable with `printenv`

However, Kitty is not seeing the variable, provable by running `show_kitty_env_vars` from Kitty.

The issue is that for my chosen Terminal, Kitty, its config file runs before any Shell scripts.

How can I set this variable system wide so it is accessible before my Terminal starts.

Comment: `if system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep -q "Studio Display"; then whatever="something"; fi`

Comment: Perfect, want to add that as an answer so I can mark as such? Thanks

Comment: Whoever closed this - no, this is not a duplicate of that. The question was about setting an env based on a connected monitor, not how to use grep in a bash statement. That just happens to be part of a suggested solution. SMH

Comment: I added a second duplicate which covers conditional assignments. This is IMHO too trivial to stay open but if you can focus on a specific problem which is not solved by existing questions, we can certainly think about reopening.

Comment: Amended the question

Comment: When you have a shell running in a terminal, the terminal gets environment variables from the process that started it, _not_ from the shell that it starts. Putting anything in your `.zshrc` is too late to help -- that file gets executed after the terminal has already finished starting and then invoked a shell as a child process. This isn't just "for kitty", it's true everywhere.

Comment: We have existing Q&A that describes how to set environment variables for processes started from the Finder; those answers will apply just as much to your terminal as to anything else. (You could also wrap your terminal's startup with a script that performs your logic and sets the variable if/as desired _before_ executing the terminal itself -- again, none of this is specific to that terminal process, and is the same thing you could do with any other tool on any other UNIXy operating system).

Comment: ...in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-on-os-x, note in particular the answers suggesting `launchctl setenv`. Granted, that's not the approach I'd use -- I'd go the wrapper route.

Comment: Separately, moving the goalposts repeatedly is problematic. If you have a new question, ask a new question. (But search before asking.)

Comment: Wrapping an app on MacOS is tricky, the app directory tree is owned by the app and so whatever changes you make (if you figure out how to hack it) could be lost in the next app upgrade.